# Serializing a List of S4 objects

Tags: r, dataframe, serialization, r-s4

I have a list of S4 objects and i need a dataframe where each object of the list is in one row. I want to use the serialize() function for the convertion of the objects.

```
object_list # list of S4 objects

objects<-serialize(object_list,connection=NULL)
```

My problem is, that the output of 'objects' is a very long raw()-vector. Is means that all S4 object are converted in one raw().
It looks like this:
[1] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 01 03 19 00 00 04 02 00 ...

I found now way to solve this problem with any loop. The serializion should take each S4-object and convert it and not all together in one big vector.

At the end I want to add each vector (from each single S4 object) in a dataframe.

| ... | objects |
| --- | --- |
| ... | 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 |
| ... | 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 |
| ... | ... |

I hope someone can help me, thank you!

Comment: Do you mind adding a reproducible example?

Comment: ── ClassyFire Object ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── classyfireR v0.3.6 ── 
Object Size: 14.9 Kb 
 
Info: 
• InChIKey=FFRYUAVNPBUEIC-UHFFFAOYSA-N
  
• O=C1NC2=CC=CC=C2N=C1
  
• Classification Version: 2.1
  
kingdom : Organic compounds
└─superclass : Organoheterocyclic compounds
  └─class : Diazanaphthalenes
    └─subclass : Benzodiazines
      └─level 5 : Quinoxalines

Comment: This is one example of the object and i have a list of them

Comment: If I serialze only 1 object of the list "serialize(Classification[[1]],connection=NULL)" Im getting the the raw() vector of it, but if i am serialize the whole list 1 I'm getting a big raw() vector and not a vector of each object

Comment: I assume one could `lapply` over the list of objects and `serialize` not the list of objects but each objetct on its own. I still fail to see a reproducible example using which one could try that idea. Try `lapply` and/or read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have tried a for loop for the iteration of each object on its own, but the raw-vector look like the same                                                                                                                      for (i in 1:length(objects) {
  output <- serialize(objects[[i]],connection=NULL)
}                                                                                                                            And which function do u mean to put in the lapply()-function?

Comment: `lapply` ist just an alternative for `for`. If you prefer `for` than that is ok, foret `lapply`. But as the `for`loop is written above, the value of `output` will be overwritten in every turn of the loop. Finally you only have the last of the many `serialize` values.

Comment: Yes, so I need a if/else condition in my `for` loop? It seems that I have never created a loop without overwriting.

Comment: I can put an explanation of how to use the loops here in an answer. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking a reproducible example let's say we have a list of somethings

```
sth <- list(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

and we have a function that takes one something and returns a raw:

```
f <- function(x) return(as.raw(x-10))
```

to apply `f` to every item in `sth` we could use `lapply` as in:

```
lapply(sth, f)
```

of if you prefer to name the function first, `Map`

```
Map(f, sth)
```

which will both return a list as result. If this list can be simplified to a vector, like a list of raws can, we can use `sapply` instead of `lapply`:

```
> sapply(sth, f)
[1] 01 02 03 04 05
```

or call `unlist` after `Map`:

```
> unlist(Map(f, sth))
[1] 01 02 03 04 05
```

So now we have vectors that we can add as a column to a `data.frame` as will be shown below.

Alternatively, we can use a `for` loop with some variable `i` but we will then need some accumulator `acc` to gather the results from the different repetitions within the loop:

```
acc = NULL      # tell R this is an identifier.
for(i in 1:length(sth))
  acc = append(acc, f(sth[[i]]))        
print(acc)
```

Or without the `append` function:

```
acc = NULL 
for(i in 1:length(sth))
  acc[i] = f(sth[[i]])        
print(acc)
```

To make the resulting vectors a column in a `data.frame` we first need a data.frame:

```
sth <- list(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

f <- function(x) return(as.raw(x-10))

dafra <- data.frame(id = 1:5, letter = letters[5:9])
dafra$objects = sapply(sth, f)
print(dafra)
```

Comment: Thank you for ur detailed answer. I have used the following command: ```output <-list(vector())
for (i in 1:length(objects)) {
  output[[i]] <- serialize(objects[[i]], connection=NULL)
}
output``` Now I have the raw-vectors in a list. This list is looking like this: `[[1]] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 [[2]] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 [[3]] 58 .....  The raw vectors have different lenghts. Is there a way to convert this list with the raw-vectors to a dataframe? as.dataframe did not work because a different number of rows.

Comment: I found the solution: ```data.frame(I(output))``` I need the I() function to create a dataframe.